# «Être cache/cash»? Qu’est-ce que ça veut dire?

Tags: sens, régionalismes, anglicismes

Entendu [ici](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRJZ7enZ3qc) à 2:39 et après, à propos de la langue des signes des sourds-muets :

> — Est-ce qu’elle est **plus cache** cette langue ?
>   — Ah oui ils sont très directs, **très caches**, beaucoup moins *euh* politiques/stratégiques, ils disent les choses... Si un sourd t’aime pas tu l’sais tout d’suite

Google ne me semble pas d’une aide énorme pour cette expression, et bien que francophone de naissance, je ne l’avais jamais entendu avant. Il me semble néanmoins que l’[intervieweuse](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1922) et l’actrice se sont très bien comprises lorsque l’utilisation est arrivée. Il doit probablement y avoir ici un usage avec lequel je ne suis pas familier, quelque usage régional ou émergeant qui n’a pas encore inondé les terres québécoises. Je suppose aussi qu’il s’agit d’un adjectif, même si le [TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/cache) ne fait mention de rien en ce sens.

Quelqu’un peut aider ?

Comment: [**FAMILIER**](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/familier) Qui a l'habitude de (quelque chose) à cause d'une pratique courante [...]
♦ **Familier avec qqc.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Il s'agit de l'anglicisme *cash*.

Ici, être cash signifie être direct, franc, ne pas prendre de pincettes.

L'Académie française [n'apprécie pas](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/cash)...

Comment: Que dire??? Je me sens idiot, mais merci de me sortir de mon ignorance.

Comment: @Montéedelait on n'a pas toujours les mêmes anglicismes d'un côté ou de l'autre de l'Atlantique... ;-)

Comment: Quand on voit l'alternative proposée par l'académie francaise "Être d’une franchise un peu brutale", cet anglicisme a encore de beaux jours devant lui...